# Disable spaces input phone field in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I have a Form with a phone number field and I need disable space key in this field for send only numbers to my CRM.

I tried this function but not disable the space key. ¿What's wrong?

```html
    function wpf_dev_disalbe_space() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
             
            jQuery( '.wpf-disable-space input' ).keydown(function(e) {
                 
                if (event.key === ' ') {
                    return false;
                }
                 
            });
             
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'wpf_dev_disalbe_space', 10 );
```

Thanks

Comment: try checking the keycode instead: `event.keyCode === 32`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ".your-form" class with the CF7 form main class by adding the following JS code. You'll see the magic happen. Happy coding!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         
        jQuery( '.your-form-class input' ).keydown(function(e) {
             
            if (event.key === ' ') {
                return false;
            }
             
        });
         
});
</script>
```